# Windows virtual key codes

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, key

How can I implement a function like `std::string VirtualKeyCodeToStdString(UCHAR key)` which returns virtual keys descriptions?

Example: input is `VK_CAPITAL`, return value is `std::string("Caps Lock")`

Comment: Typically, each question should be separate. Consider removing your second question here, asking it separately, and linking back to this question.

Comment: @DeathTails edited.

Comment: GetKeyNameText() provides a built-in description.  Beware it takes a scan code, not a virtual key code so use MapVirtualKeyEx() if necessary.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to convert UCHAR Virtual-Key Codes into std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959649/how-to-convert-uchar-virtual-key-codes-into-stdstring)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no full answer. Thank you everybody for helping. After more research I wrote complete function that converts `virtualKey` to `std::string` description.

*** std::basic_string < TCHAR > Version: ***

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

tstring VirtualKeyCodeToString(UCHAR virtualKey)
{
    UINT scanCode = MapVirtualKey(virtualKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    TCHAR szName[128];
    int result = 0;
    switch (virtualKey)
    {
        case VK_LEFT: case VK_UP: case VK_RIGHT: case VK_DOWN:
        case VK_RCONTROL: case VK_RMENU:
        case VK_LWIN: case VK_RWIN: case VK_APPS:
        case VK_PRIOR: case VK_NEXT:
        case VK_END: case VK_HOME:
        case VK_INSERT: case VK_DELETE:
        case VK_DIVIDE:
        case VK_NUMLOCK:
            scanCode |= KF_EXTENDED;
        default:
            result = GetKeyNameText(scanCode << 16, szName, 128);
    }
    if(result == 0)
        throw std::system_error(std::error_code(GetLastError(), std::system_category()),
                                "WinAPI Error occured.");
    return szName;
}
```

***std::string version:***

```
std::string VirtualKeyCodeToString(UCHAR virtualKey)
{
    UINT scanCode = MapVirtualKey(virtualKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    CHAR szName[128];
    int result = 0;
    switch (virtualKey)
    {
        case VK_LEFT: case VK_UP: case VK_RIGHT: case VK_DOWN:
        case VK_RCONTROL: case VK_RMENU:
        case VK_LWIN: case VK_RWIN: case VK_APPS:
        case VK_PRIOR: case VK_NEXT:
        case VK_END: case VK_HOME:
        case VK_INSERT: case VK_DELETE:
        case VK_DIVIDE:
        case VK_NUMLOCK:
            scanCode |= KF_EXTENDED;
        default:
            result = GetKeyNameTextA(scanCode << 16, szName, 128);
    }
    if(result == 0)
        throw std::system_error(std::error_code(GetLastError(), std::system_category()),
                                "WinAPI Error occured.");
    return szName;
}
```

Comment: Your *std::string version* needs to call `GetKeyNameTextA`.

Comment: @IInspectable it depends on settings. But you true.

Comment: Those external settings are outside your control. That's why you need to be explicit about the function version, when being explicit about the character type.

Comment: It's more clear to use `KF_EXTENDED` instead of hard-coded `0x100`.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to convert the VK code to a text representation of the key is to:

1. Use `MapVirtualKey` to convert the VK code to a scan code.
2. Do a bit shift to convert that value into a long where bits 16-23 are the scan code
3. Use `GetKeyNameText` to obtain the name of the key.

For example:

```
WCHAR name[1024];
UINT scanCode = MapVirtualKeyW(VK_CAPITAL, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
LONG lParamValue = (scanCode << 16);
int result = GetKeyNameTextW(lParamValue, name, 1024);
if (result > 0)
{
    std::wcout << name << endl; // Output: Caps Lock
}
```

If you're doing this in response to a `WM_KEYDOWN` or other message that passes the scan code in the `LPARAM` you can skip the first two steps, since those are just there to massage the VK code into a properly formatted input for `GetKeyNameText`. For more information about the function and the format of the first parameter to `GetKeyNameText` see the [documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300.aspx)

*Note: I used the W variant on the API calls, so you'd actually need to use a `std::wstring` to pass the key name, but you can change it easily to use the A version. Also, if you need to pass a keyboard layout to get the proper scan code, you can use `MapVirtualKeyEx`.*