# Virtual Key Code Constant from decimal value

Tags: c++, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I'm currently building a function that detects keyboard and mouse events using Windows Hooks and I'd like to use as minimum code as possible.

I've seen some solutions that as receiving the code from `vkCode`, checks it with a switch case as the example behind:

```
switch(vkCode)
{
   case 0x10:                       
      std::cout << "The constant is: VK_SHIFT\n"; 
   break; 
}
```

But what I'd like to do is reversing the "`std:cout << vkCode;`" code line that returns me the decimal code of the key with a function that entering with the `vkCode` as parameter returns me the **Virtual Key Code Constant** as it follows:

**CODE:**
`std::cout << vkConstName(0x10);`

**ANSWER:**
$VK_SHIFT

**CODE:**
`std::cout << vkConstName(0x10);`

**ANSWER:**
$VK_SHIFT

My reference material is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes;

Comment: Note: this question has nothing to do with the hooking itself so you might want to reconsider some of the tags you used.

Comment: You can write a function to do this. I don't believe there is one in the WIndows API, at least in 25 years of writing keyboard mapping code I've never seen one.

Comment: [Windows virtual key codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100667/windows-virtual-key-codes) may help but in my experience, years ago to be fair, `GetKeyNameText` didn't do exactly what we wanted so we just made a big table of the keys and their names.